# How to Switch Between NavBar Tabs with a Button R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I need the user to click a button and be taken to a different `tabPanel` of a `navbarPage`. Here is a simple app where this could be implemented. How can I achieve this?

```
ui <- shinyUI(
 navbarPage('Test App',
  tabPanel('Page 1',
   p('This is the first tab'), br(),
   actionButton('jumpToP2', 'Jump to Second Tab')
  ),

  tabPanel('Page 2',
   p('This is the second tab'),
   actionButton('jumpToP1', 'Jump to First Tab')
  )
 )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$jumpToP2,{
    ## Switch active tab to 'Page 2'
  })

  observeEvent(input$jumpToP1,{
    ## Switch active tab to 'Page 1'
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: this works with some minor changes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309328/generic-button-for-go-to-next-and-previous-tabitem-shiny

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `updateTabsetPanel` to switch between different `tabPanel`s. See the documentation and example codes at https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateTabsetPanel.html. The code below should fulfill your requirements.

```
ui <- navbarPage('Test App',id = "inTabset",
                 tabPanel(title = "Panel 1", value = "panel1", 
                          actionButton('jumpToP2', 'Jump to Second Tab')),
                 tabPanel(title = "Panel 2", value = "panel2", 
                          actionButton('jumpToP1', 'Jump to First Tab'))
        )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$jumpToP2, {
        updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset",
                          selected = "panel2")
    })

    observeEvent(input$jumpToP1, {
        updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset",
                          selected = "panel1")
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Now you can also use `updateNavbarPage()` and `updateNavlistPanel()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure that this really the best way for you to design your U... Do you know that `tabPanel()` will act pretty much the same way as an `actionButton()` will in this case?

```
ui <- navbarPage('Test App',id = "inTabset",
             tabPanel(title = "Panel 1", uiOutput("panel1")),                       
             tabPanel(title = "Panel 2", uiOutput("panel2")) 
                      )
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$panel1 <- renderUI({
    #your UI data
    })
    output$panel2 <- renderUI({
    #your UI data
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```