# Disable walking between tabs Shiny

Tags: r, tabs, shiny, switching, shinyjs

I have shiny application with several tabs. 
The problem is that I want to walk between tabs with button, not by clicking on the tab. How I can disable clicking on tabs?
Small example of code:

```
ui <- navbarPage('Test App', id = "inTabset",
                 tabPanel(title = "Panel 1", value = "panel1", 
                          actionButton('jumpToP2', 'Jump to Secon Tab')),
                 tabPanel(title = "Panel 2", value = "panel2", 
                          actionButton('jumpToP1', 'Jump to First Tab'))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$jumpToP2, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset",
                      selected = "panel2")
  })

  observeEvent(input$jumpToP1, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset",
                      selected = "panel1")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible workaround. We can use `shinyjs` to disable the `navbar` buttons, and add some `CSS` to change the cursor to default when hovering the navigation bar.

There may be simpler ways that I am not aware of, so I am curious to see other possible solution approaches :) Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- navbarPage('Test App', id = "inTabset",
                 tabPanel(title = "Panel 1", value = "panel1", 
                          actionButton('jumpToP2', 'Jump to Secon Tab')),
                 tabPanel(title = "Panel 2", value = "panel2", 
                          actionButton('jumpToP1', 'Jump to First Tab')),
                 useShinyjs(),
                 tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.navbar-nav a {cursor: default}')))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  shinyjs::disable(selector = '.navbar-nav a')

  observeEvent(input$jumpToP2, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset",
                      selected = "panel2")
  })

  observeEvent(input$jumpToP1, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset",
                      selected = "panel1")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yet, it's very interesting problem in several ways. For example, how could I walk between tabs on the way back without  a button (from tab2 to tab1), but ahead I must push a button (from tab1 to tab2)? Hope i'll find answer to that question too ^_^

Comment: Hi @Lesley, there are multiple ways to do this, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309328/generic-button-for-go-to-next-and-previous-tabitem-shiny). If your tabs are numbered, you could also do something like `observeEvent(input$btn_next, {selected = as.numeric(gsub("[^\\d]+", "", input$sidebar, perl=TRUE));updateTabItems(session, 'sidebar', paste0('panel',selected+1))})` But this sounds like another question, so please consider accepting this answer if it solved the current issue, and open a new question if you have follow-up questions. Thanks!